# Studio Monitor's Cone not making sound after playing loud music through it

Tags: electrical-engineering, audio-engineering

I was playing some very loud pop music through a studio monitor (ADAM A8X), and after about 5 seconds the sound stopped coming out of the cone and only came through the speaker. After shutting it off for a few minutes and trying again, no sound was coming from the cone. I assume I broke something, but don't know where to start in terms of fixing it. Any advice?

Comment: What do you mean by _cone_ vs. _speaker_?  Since you appear to be using non-standard terms, could you find a picture of the thing, and annotate it with where the sound is or is not emitting?  Note that the big round thing that dominates the face of the thing is a _woofer_; the little rectangular thing above the woofer is the tweeter.  If sound comes out one but not the other, then you probably burnt out the crossover or amplifier.

Comment: I mean the woofer

Comment: So just to be clear, the tweeter is still working, but the woofer is not?

Comment: Generally you will hear distortion before you burn out the coil of a speaker. That's a clue that you're overdriving it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably overheated the *voice coil* in the *woofer* (large paper cone speaker), causing it to burn out.

But if you are lucky, there might be a fuse inside the speaker box protecting the woofer- and if you replace that fuse, you will be back in action again.

The most likely place for the fuse to be is in the *crossover assembly*- so it is now time for you to take the speaker apart and look for a fuse. While you have it apart you can also disconnect the wires leading from the crossover to the woofer and test the woofer terminals with an ohmmeter. they should read somewhere between 3 and 7 ohms. If they read off-scale high (a zillion ohms!) then you have blown up the voice coil and you'll have to replace the woofer.